# finding first commit of a file in git

Tags: git

The situation: I have a tar.gz of a release from a github project but would like to work out which commit this was taken from. It doesn't appear to have been tagged or is it obvious from commit message themselves.

So I can calculate sha1 of the files, but would like to work out which commit these belong to?

Calling git wizards!

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is an interesting problem. He has files that originated from a Git repository, but currently aren't under version control, and he wants to know what version they correspond to. It's a fair question.

Comment: Upvoted. It is an excellent question that exposes the awesome way that Git stores history.

Comment: thanks for both great answers. I'd assumed at the time of asking the question that the tar.gz is an exact export of the repo - but having tried both methods it appears there's only a commit very close, the difference being on README files which appear to have been manually edited for the release. So giving the credit to the diff based answer, but that's not to say the other wasn't an excellent answer also. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the git-stored hash doesn't just include the file contents (and, in theory, hash collisions happen anyhow), in order to be really sure you've got the right version of the file you need to compare the contents.

```
for rev in $(git log --format=%H -- /path/to/file); do
   git diff --quiet $x:/path/to/file my-current-file;
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo $x;
   fi
done
```

In English: iterate over the revisions that changed the file, in reverse order. For each such revision, diff the version of the file there with the outside-the-tree file. If the two files are identical, print the revision hash.

If you want to do this for the *whole tarball*, you can do the same but diff the whole tree instead of a single file (and omit the file path as an argument to `git log`) - use whatever tolerant diff options you like.

Comment: You need to match all the files in the tar to find out where the tar came from.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk I added a note to the end of the answer about this.

Comment: In this case, it might take a long time to find. But you do get rid of the file attributes ambiguity.

Comment: tolerant diff options would give you false results. You want exact matches.

Answer (score 2):

This method may be tricky due to file attributes. Assuming they are unchanged or you look at what the repo stores, ensure they are the same. Commit this to the repository and then take a look at the hash of the tree.

```
git show -s --pretty=format:%T HEAD
```

Now walk all commits in the repo and see if any of them have a tree of the same hash.

```
git log --all --format=%H
```

will give you all the commit hashes. Now pipe this to show the tree hash

```
git log --all --format=%H \
  | xargs -n 1 git show -s --pretty='format:%H %T' \
  | gerp <hash of your tree>
```

If the tar contained exactly the same structure including permissions, the output will show the SHA1s of the commits that have the same tree.

**Searching for the top level tree SHA1 will be FAST.**