# Git - show file diff between HEAD and initial (first) version

Tags: git, diff

Suppose some repository at some point has created a file `test.txt` and committed it to the repository with some data. The file might not be present in the repository's initial commit.

Next, a lot of commits make changes to this file.
Now, I want to produce `diff` output that shows the difference between the initial (first) version of the file `test.txt` and the current (`HEAD`).
How do I do this?

EDIT: Question changed to note that the file might not be present in initial commit.

Comment: are you asking how to determine the state of `test.txt` on it's initial commit to the repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, get the hash for the first commit that has `test.txt` in it.

```
git log --oneline --diff-filter=A -- text.txt
```

Than, diff that hash with `HEAD`.  (Make sure you have the current `HEAD` pulled first.)

```
git diff [hash from previous command] text.txt
```

These two commands can be combined together

```
git diff `git log --oneline --diff-filter=A -- text.txt | awk '{print $1}'` HEAD text.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to add in the question that the file to be checked does not necessarily appear in the initial commit. My bad. I edited the question. I need to find the commit which first introduces the file I suppose.

Comment: @vatsug, did you use @soundslikeodd's script?  It does **exactly** what you're asking.  The `diff-filter` limits the log to just adds and since the file was only added once, you get the hash of the first commit of that file (whenever that is).

Comment: @PatrickSteele Sorry. Did not see the edit containing the handy oneliner. Thank you! I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff 27fa75e test.txt
```

Where `27fa75e` is the hash of the initial version. You can find that hash using `git log`.

If the file didn't exist in the original commit, `git` will let you know that it is a new file. To find the first commit with the file you can use `git log`:

```
git log test.txt
```

This will give you a log of all the commits with that file, the last of which will be when the file was first committed. Note that this will not help if the file was renamed, and if it was it will be much more difficult to track down the original version. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232363/finding-first-commit-of-a-file-in-git) discusses how to dive into a repository and extract commits: you have to walk back through the relevant commits and do file comparisons to find the files you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to add in the question that the file to be checked does not necessarily appear in the initial commit. My bad. I edited the question.

Comment: That's a little unclear: if the file doesn't exist in the initial commit, then the difference between the file-as-it-exists-in-the-initial-commit and the file-as-it-exists-in-HEAD is simply the totality of the file in your current HEAD? Can you clarify what you mean by 'doesn't exist'?

Comment: I mean I want to get the diff between the first version of that particular file (the first commit that touches the file) and HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. I use `git log --reverse` to get the hash of the first commit which touches the file and compare to HEAD:

```
git diff `git log --pretty=format:"%h" --reverse test.txt | head -1` HEAD test.txt
```

Comment: I'd like to note that both previous answers include variations on this. Also if the file was renamed or moved, you will only get the first commit with the new name.

Comment: How to make it handle renames and removals, then?

Comment: 'Removals' doesn't make sense here, but I've added a link to my answer dealing with the much more complicated issue of walking back through commits.

Answer (score -1):

Based on soundslikeodd's answer. Not actually an answer.

This is the script I wrote for myself to use and why not share it here... It takes any file under git version control and `git diff`s it do the file's earliest version. I think this will not work reliably if the same file was added multiple times (and removed in between) and I haven't thoroughly tested this. The thing I did though, is to make sure that I can use this script from anywhere (I set it as an alias).

```
#!/bin/bash
#takes a file under git version control as the first argument. diffs with the files original version.
cd $(dirname "$1")
git diff $(git log --oneline --diff-filter=A -- $1 | awk '{print $1}') HEAD $1
```

The reason I add this as an answer is just that it wouldn't be nicely formatted as a comment. Please tell me if this kind of answer is not appreciated here.